# React.js: Передать состояние всем дочерним элементам

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Предисловие**

В некоторых реакт-библиотеках (например, `material-ui`) можно передавать данные как угодно далеко/глубоко в древо. Работает это так: все наше приложение оборачивается в некий провайдер. Затем, когда нам нужно воспользоваться каким-то глобальным свойством/состоянием мы используем специальную функцию из этой же библиотеки - оборачиваем дочерний компонент в нее и отдаем на экспорт, вот так:

```
// App.js

import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = { //объект со свойствами темы интерфейса
    color: "red",
};

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}> //обернули приложение в провайдер и передали тему пропсами
      <Root />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}


// MyComponent, где-то внутри <Root>

import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div>{props.theme.color}</div>; // берем данные из темы
}

export default withTheme()(MyComponent); // воспользовавшись специальной функцией из библиотеки мы можем достучаться до объекта темы
```

**Вопрос:** Как это делается под капотом? Какие способы передачи данных куда угодно вы знаете? (без постоянной передачи пропсов)

Comment: Ну это же Redux подход

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach я еще не знаком с редакс. Он делает то же самое?

Comment: Да, делает именно то что вы описали